# iFrame text alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Im using an iFrame for a WYSIWYG, and would like to add a button that will align all the content within the iFrame to the center.

I tried adding "text-align:center;" on the class of the iFrame but that did nothing.

How can I do this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to align the iframe itself or change the styling of its content?

Comment: @rioc0719 he clearly said he need to align `content within iframe` not iframe

Comment: you can simply put div on top of that iframe and then align that i will automatically align all contents inside that

Comment: if you are loading another page in the iframe you will need to center the content in that pages code

Comment: I'm trying to have any user input within the iFrame be aligned to the center. There is no other page being loaded. @ancient, I tried that and it simply aligned the iframe itself and not the content inside of it, can you give me an example with code?

Answer (score 0):

I may be incorrect, but my understanding is that you can't modify the contents of an iFrame, unless you have access to the site where the iFrame's content is coming from.

See [this](http://.center%20%7B%20text-align:%20center;%20%7D%20%20%20-----%20%20%20%3Ciframe%20class=%22center%22%3E%20.%20.%20.%20%3C/iframe%3E) for more details.

To add, using "text-align" will only align the iFrame itself as a whole, but not the content.

Answer (score 0):

An iframe behaves as a separate independent web page, so you'll need to change the HTML inside the iframe. Due to the same origin policy, you can only do this if the iframe content comes from the same domain name as the parent page.

If the domain names do match, you can do something like this in Javascript:

```
function center_iframe() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('myiframe'),
        iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    iframeDocument.body.style.textAlign = 'center';
}
```

This might be too simplistic for your needs (and whether it works depends on the HTML inside the iframe), but [here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/fhds6kLq/) anyway.